# Python how to compare string in a list with dict

Tags: python

I have a code like this:
It will print `Student`

```
d= u'pen hahahahaha'
area  = [u'Apple',u'Banana',u'lemon']
area2 = [ u'pen',u'book',u'chair' ]
area3 = [u'father',u'mother']
if any(d.startswith(i) for i in area):
    category = 'Fruit'
    print 'Fruit'
elif any(d.startswith(i) for i in area2):
    category = 'Student'
    print 'Student'
elif any(d.startswith(i) for i in area3):
    category = 'family'
    print 'family'
```

I want to know how to edit it to a mode like this:

```
aa = [{"Fruit":[u'Apple',u'Banana',u'lemon']},
      {"Student":[ u'pen',u'book',u'chair' ]},
      {"Family":[u'father',u'mother']}]
```

So I can compare if `'pen hahahahaha'` in `{"Student":[ u'pen',u'book',u'chair' ]}`
save `category = 'Student'`

I think for a while but have no idea,please guide me.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `aa` a dictionary like:

```
aa = {"Fruit":[u'Apple',u'Banana',u'lemon'],
      "Student":[ u'pen',u'book',u'chair' ],
      "Family":[u'father',u'mother']}

obj = 'pen'   
for key in aa:
    if obj in aa[key]:
        print(obj + ' is in ' + key)
```

**edit:**
May be this will suit your requirement more

```
aa = {"Fruit":[u'Apple',u'Banana',u'lemon'],
      "Student":[ u'pen',u'book',u'chair' ],
      "Family":[u'father',u'mother']}

obj = u'pen hahhah'   
for key in aa:
    for item in aa[key]:
        if obj.startswith(item):
            print(obj + ' is in ' + key)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use loop:

```
categories = {
    "Fruit": [u'Apple', u'Banana', u'lemon'],
    "Student": [u'pen', u'book', u'chair'],
    "Family": [u'father', u'mother']
}


def get_category(value):
    for cat, cat_entries in categories.iteritems():
        for cat_entry in cat_entries:
            if value.startswith(cat_entry):
                return cat
    return None


print get_category('pen hahahahaha')
```

Output:

```
Student
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aa = [{"Fruit":[u'Apple',u'Banana',u'lemon']},
  {"Student":[ u'pen',u'book',u'chair' ]},
  {"Family":[u'father',u'mother']}]
d=u'pen haaaaaa'
print [ x.keys()[0] for x in aa for y in x.values()[0] if y in d.split() ]
```